# A coisotropic submanifold is locally given by the fibers of a submersion with coordinates in involution

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M, \omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and $Q \subset M$ a coisotropic submanifold of codimension $k$. I'm trying to prove that for every $x \in Q$, there exists an open subset $U \subset M$ containing $x$ and a submersion $F : U \to \mathbb{R}^k$ whose coordinates are in involution (i.e. $\{F_i, F_j\} = 0$) such that $F^{-1}(0) = Q \cap U$.

I proved this in the case $Q$ is Lagrangian, as a corollary of the fact that $Q$ would have a neighborhood symplectomorphic to a neighborhood of the $0$ section in $T^{*}Q$, which would allow us to get "adapted" Darboux coordinates: $(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ Darboux coordinates around $x$ where $Q$ is described by $y_1 = \cdots = y_n = 0$. Then we can just let $F(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n) = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ and it works.

In the general coisotropic case, I can't figure out what to do. It seems likely one should be able to get Darboux coordinates where $Q$ is determined by $y_{n - k + 1} = \cdots = y_n = 0$, but I can't see how.

Comment: Did  you try asking this on http://mathoverflow.net?

Comment: It doesn't seem particularly fit as this is just a question from my introductory symplectic geometry class.

Comment: The idea behind the proof is to use induction on the codimension. You can find the proof as Proposition 3.24 on page 41 of the lecture notes of Eckhard Meinrenken: http://www.math.toronto.edu/mein/teaching/LectureNotes/sympl.pdf